# Copying a file after creating directories in c#

Tags: c#, copy

My File.Copy(xxx,xxx, true) is throwing an unhandled exception I understand that File.copy does not allow me to use a directory but in my case my filename can change every time I go through the loop. I need the filename to be the same as it appears in my source folder. Here is what I have so far. Any Ideas? I looked at MSDN but it defines my problem, not a solution. Any help appreciated.

```
//Get Data from Filename
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "Result*.xml");
Regex date = new Regex(@"(?<month>[1-9]|[0-2])_(?<day>\d{2})_(?<year>\d{4})", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

foreach (string s in files)
{
    Match m = date.Match(s);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        //Pass Groups to String
        string month = m.Groups["month"].Value;
        string day = m.Groups["day"].Value;
        string year = m.Groups["year"].Value;

        //Create Dir
        var paths = new string[] { targetPath, year, month, day };
        string result = paths.Aggregate(Path.Combine);                        
        Directory.CreateDirectory(result);

        //Copy file
        File.Copy(s, result, true);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Shall I look into my crystal ball and guess what your exception is, or would you like to tell us instead? There's 8 different possible exceptions that can be thrown by `File.Copy`

Comment: I think you're confused when you say File.Copy doesn't allow you to use a directory - it absolutely does. You're supposed to pass the *full path* of the files in question, not just the names.  See my answer below.

Comment: Also, please learn to read [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx). If you had, you'd notice that `result` "...cannot be a directory" which is what you're passing it. Additionally it has examples that show using a path (I don't know where you got that it doesn't allow a path).

Comment: Thank you tnw. my exception was "The target file "C:\Users\wike01\Desktop\sorted\2009\5\14" is a directory, not a file." in case your crystal ball was malfunctioning. I made a mistake by not proofing my post well enough. I typed path but I should have said directory. I have this corrected now thanks to Magnus but your sarcasm was extremely helpful..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mistake is that you aren't including the filename in the destination parameter.

```cs
string filename = Path.GetFileName(s);
string newPath = Path.Combine(result, filename);
File.Copy(s, newPath, true);
```

Comment: That nails it on the head sir. Thank you.